# How to save a user's preference and get it when Java app restarts?

Tags: java

I have a Java application that lets the user browse and pick a file (the info is read from the filepath). I want to be able to save this file path to the user's computer (or find a better way) so that I can automatically retrieve the file when the user reboots the application. How could I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Why did that fail? What did you try next? Why did THAT fail? What are you currently trying? Why is it failing?

Comment: By "the user's computer" you mean on the machine the app is running on? Why not just use the `Preferences` API? Or read/save a property file? Or use an embedded DB? Or...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not using any database in your project, the easiest way to do what you want is saving an INI file.

If you use this approach I would recommend that you take a look at this library: http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/

Then, you can configure an INI file like this:

```
[userfile]
 file = userfile.txt
 path = path\to\the\file
```

Hope it helps...